# How to stop leaking IDisposables with an IObservable<IDisposable>?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, idisposable, resource-leak

I had a bug in my production code which I tracked down and managed to create a test case to reproduce. I am creating

```
IObservable<IDisposable>
```

instances and using a serial disposable in the subscription to keep at most one item alive at a time. It's a neat way to add graphic objects to a scene and remove them when updates are available.

However the following test case shows the subtle bug.

```
using System;
using System.Reactive.Concurrency;
using System.Reactive.Disposables;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using FluentAssertions;
using Microsoft.Reactive.Testing;
using Xunit;

namespace WeinCadSW.Spec
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This test case demonstrates problems with streams of IDisposables.
    /// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37936537/how-to-stop-leaking-idisposables-with-an-iobservableidisposable
    /// </summary>
    public class ObservableDisposableSpec : ReactiveTest
    {
        TestScheduler _Scheduler = new TestScheduler();
        [Fact]
        public void ShouldWork()
        {
            var o = _Scheduler.CreateHotObservable
                (OnNext(100, "A")
                , OnNext(200, "B")
                , OnNext(250, "C")
                , OnNext(255, "D")
                , OnNext(258, "E")
                , OnNext(600, "F")
                );

            var disposablesCreated = 0;
            var disposabledDisposed = 0;
            var oo = o.Select
                (s =>
                {
                    disposablesCreated++;
                    return Disposable.Create(() => disposabledDisposed++);
                })
                .Delay(TimeSpan.FromTicks(10), _Scheduler);


            IDisposable sub = Disposable.Empty;
            _Scheduler.ScheduleAbsolute(null, 0, (Func<IScheduler, object, IDisposable>)((scheduler, state) =>
            {
                sub = oo.SubscribeDisposable();
                return Disposable.Empty;
            }));
            _Scheduler.ScheduleAbsolute(null, 605, (Func<IScheduler, object, IDisposable>)((scheduler, state) =>
            {
                sub.Dispose();
                return Disposable.Empty;
            }));

            _Scheduler.Start();

            // This test will fail here because 6 disposables are created. 
            disposablesCreated.Should().Be(6);
            disposabledDisposed.Should().Be(6); // but is actually 5

        }

    }
```

and the **SubscribeDisposable** method that is at the heart of the problem.

```
    public static class Extensions
    {

        public static IDisposable SubscribeDisposable (this IObservable<IDisposable> o )
        {
            var d = new SerialDisposable();

            var s = o.Subscribe(v =>
            {
                d.Disposable = v;
            });

            return new CompositeDisposable(s, d);

        }


    }

}
```

When I dispose the subscription, one more IDisposable is generated and is never sent to the subscription.

6 disposables are generated but one is leaked. This is because of the delay I put into the system to model scheduling delays in the real system.

So my question is.

Is it possible to write a **SubscribeDisposable** similar to the above that will not leak IDisposables.

Comment: I don't understand reactive, but where is `SubscribeDisposable` used?

Comment: I've updated the test case to fully demonstrate SubscribeDisposable.

Comment: Isn't that because the last event is at time 600, but the sub is disposed at 605, meaning that it will never get disposed?

Comment: Yeah. Because of the delay the item generated at 600 will be delivered at 610 but the subscription is disposed at 605 thus causing the leak.

Comment: So if you put check of `d.IsDisposed` before setting `d.Disposable`, then it will get hit? The `Disposable` setter should really throw an exception if the `SerialDisposable` is already disposed.

Comment: That will not help the extra disposable from leaking.

Comment: No, I would just like to make sure that is really the problem.

Comment: SerialDisposable is allowed to accept new Disposables after being itself Disposed. It just immediately disposes them. It's in the doc.

Comment: ""If the SerialDisposable has already been disposed, assignment to this property causes immediate disposal of the given disposable object. Assigning this property disposes the previous disposable object."" from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.disposables.serialdisposable.disposable(v=vs.103).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I am firmly of the belief that there is no solution to the above question due to the contracts the RX enforces. So I've updated my code to avoid the above pattern. Instead I use.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Subscribes to the observable sequence and manages the disposables 
    /// with a serial disposable. That
    /// is before the function is called again the previous disposable is disposed.
    /// </summary>

    public static IDisposable SubscribeDisposable<T>
    (this IObservable<T> o, Func<T, IDisposable> fn, Action<Exception> errHandler)
    {
        var d = new SerialDisposable();

        var s = o.Subscribe(v =>
        {
                d.Disposable = Disposable.Empty;
                d.Disposable = fn(v) ?? Disposable.Empty;
        }, onError:errHandler);

        return new CompositeDisposable(s,d);

    }
```

Thus

```
IObservable<IDisposable>
```

is removed from my code as it seems dangerous.